# Errno::ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect) OpenSSL certificates? Ruby on Rails 2.3.15

Tags: ruby, openssl, ssl-certificate, ruby-on-rails-2, net-http

Hi all this is my first post so sorry if I do anything wrong.

I am using `Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.15` on a `centOS 6.5 VPS with openssl 1.01e ruby-gems 1.8.25, mongrel_rails server`. My app needs to connect to an API using Net::HTTP over SSL with authentication. The key detail is everything was working perfectly and suddenly with no changes on my part I started getting:

```
Errno::ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect):<br />
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:586:in `connect'<br />
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:586:in `connect'<br />
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in `do_start'<br />
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:542:in `start'<br />
```

According to [Errno::ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966446/errnoeconnreset-connection-reset-by-peer-ssl-connect) and a few other answers around the web I am led to believe my openSSL certificates are outdated (that is the only explanation I can imagine for why the problem started on previously working code). I read the linked article on fixing the openSSL certificates but it only addresses OSX, and some Ubuntu info, I am using CentOS 6.5 and not using RVM. Can anyone tell me how to reset the openSSL certificates that Ruby uses on a CentOS system (if that is even my problem)? I have been stuck on this for a few days with no progress.

So far I have tried to reinstall OpenSSL using yum, reinstall ruby using /script/installruby, and I cannot update ruby gems past 1.8.25 or the server refuses to start.

Answer (score 0):

I had to upgrade to ruby 1.9.3 and force sslv3. I still have no idea how the previous code stopped working overnight with supposedly nothing changing on either end of the connection. I guess the moral of the story is don't use unsupported rubies.